# React re-rendering resets component's hover state

Tags: reactjs

I set my component to scale 1.2x when hovered over, however, when the component is re-rendered by React while I'm hovering over it, it loses the hover state for a moment and becomes small, then back to 1.2x, (see image). I want it  to stay scaled. How can I work around this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was a problem because I subscribed the whole React render function to the Redux store, causing every action to force a re-render. This was fixed by using react-redux connect instead of subscribing the render function.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, and it turns out I was declaring a functional component within a different functional component (as a helper component). When the parent state changed, it re-created the internal component, causing the actual DOM to change.

Moving the internal component outside the main functional component fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create a flexbox component on the parent of this component and add the onHover function on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `react-redux`'s connect which doesn't re-render on every action.

Because , when you use `subscribe` the  `render` function to the `Redux` store,
it causes the every action to forcefully `re-render`.